# jquery validate plugin require exact value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How can we require a user to place a specific number in a text input and validate against an exact number (or any value).  In this case 001 (starting digits of an account number).  The value 001 is a way to determine if the user is likely to have an account to proceed.

Am using jQuery.validate  - http://jqueryvalidation.org

Have the following:

For validation I have:

```
$("#form1").validate({
messages: {
acn_01: {
     required: 'Please enter a valid account number',
     range: [001,001]
     }
}
});
```

Range does not seem to work with [001] or [001,001].  Is there another method or technique to do this?

Thanks all.

Comment: The problem is your range ``001`` to ``001`` is a number so it becomes ``1`` to ``1`` and you care comparing a string to it.

Comment: Appreciate the lively comments. Both answers were good and very instructional on several levels. Yes, this is part of a larger form and I just asked for the minimal to address one small part. Suppose we didn't use range and we converted the 001 over to a string? Suppose we were looking to validate a color choice like red? Obviously range would not apply. How would we validate a text string in the same context?

Comment: @Stuff, you could use the pattern method (part of the `additional-methods.js` file) along with a regex. Or you could use the `.addMethod()` method to write your own function to create a custom rule. Posted details in my answer edits.

Comment: Perfect. For some reason your explanation off addMethod seemed to resonated better than the jquery.validate docs. Thanks to you and Dustin for your approaches and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Your code...

```
messages: {  // <- MESSAGES option
    acn_01: {
        required: 'Please enter a valid account number',
        range: [001,001]  // <- this is not a message
    }
}
```

The problem is that you are trying to put put rule parameters into the `messages` option.  The `messages` option is for custom messages and the `rules` option is for declaring the rules/paramters.

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {  // <- rules option
        acn_01: {
            required: true,   // <- rule: parameter
            range: [1, 1] // <- rule: parameter
        }
    },
    messages: { // <- messages option
        acn_01: {
            required: 'Please enter a valid account number', // <- custom message
            range: 'Please enter the number {0}'  // <- custom message
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wxfaborn/**

BTW:  You cannot use a string (`001`) or a pattern within the `range` method... it's only looking for a range of numbers, in this case from `1` up to `1`.

**EDIT**:

Otherwise, you could use the `pattern` method (part of the [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) file) along with a [regex](http://www.regexr.com) as the parameter.  Or you could use [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to write your own function, thereby creating a custom rule.

Here is a very simple demo of `.addMethod()`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == params[0];
}, "Please enter the correct value of {0}");


$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {  
        acn_01: {
            required: true,
            myRule: ["001"]
        }
    }, ....
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/wxfaborn/1/**

Comment: Lol thats a lot of code to say ``if("001" == "001")`` not to mention you have to load another plugin into the document. Just do the comparison manual with a lot less code.

Comment: Perfect.  For some reason your explanation off addMethod seemed to resonated better than the jquery.validate docs. Thanks to you and Dustin for your approaches and expertise.

Comment: @Stuff, yes, although the docs are improving slowly.  Please "accept" my answer if it solved your issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use this validate plugin when all your trying to do is compare the users input to "001"? Just make your own validate plugin that does what you want.

```
$.fn.validate001 = function(){
  if(this.val()=="001")return true;
  else return false;
};
$("#input").validate001();
```

If you need "001" to be at the beginning (but they may have numbers after that) use:

```
$.fn.validate001 = function(){
  if(this.val().indexOf("001")==0)return true;
  else return false;
};
$("#input").validate001();
```

Of if "001" needs to be at the end of the string use:

```
$.fn.validate001 = function(){
  if(this.val().indexOf("001")==this.val().length-4)return true;
  else return false;
};
$("#input").validate001();
```

I don't see a need to use a plugin for something so simple.

Comment: You are assuming that's the only thing he needs to validate... that there are no other forms or form elements.

Comment: Did they specify that there was any other data to be validated? Nope. Does this method I proposed stop them from using the validate plugin anywheres else? Nope. Does this answer do what they are asking for? Yes

Comment: Did the OP ask specifically about the jQuery Validate plugin?  Yep, twice.

Comment: The question is about validating user input, they happen to be using this plugin but no wheres do they specify "I must use this plugin". When all you have is a hammer every problem is a nail

Comment: Appreciate the lively comments.  Both answers were good and very instructional on several levels.  Yes, this is part of a larger form and I just asked for the minimal to address one small part.  Suppose we didn't use range and we converted the 001 over to a string?  Suppose we were looking to validate a color choice like red?  Obviously range would not apply. How would we validate a text string in the same context?